# Turning a list of dictionaries into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

If you have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
listofdict = [{'value1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, {'value2': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}, {'value3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}]
```

How can you turn it into a dataframe where `value1`, `value2` and `value3` are column names and the lists are the columns.

I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(listofdict)
```

But it gives me the values congested in one row and the remaining rows as NaN.

Comment: Did you try to **read the documentation** for `pd.DataFrame`, in order to understand the expected format for the data?

Comment: Does [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](/questions/38987/) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k:v for i in listofdict for k,v in i.items()})
```

Output:

```
   value1  value2 value3
0       1       5      a
1       2       4      b
2       3       3      c
3       4       2      d
4       5       1      e
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame` is expecting a single dictionary with column names as keys, so you need to fusion all these dictionaries in a single one like `{'value1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'value2': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], ... }`

You can try

```
listofdict = [{'value1':[1,2,3,4,5]}, {'value2':[5,4,3,2,1]},{'value3':['a','b','c','d','e']}]

dicofdics = {}

for dct in listofdict:
    dicofdics.update(dct)

df = pd.DataFrame(dicofdics)
df
```

| index | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | a |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | b |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | c |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | d |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | e |